# My keyframes doesn't appear on the Dopesheet at all?

Tags: animation, keyframes, dopesheet

My dopesheet's keyframes doesn't appear at all, when i add a keyframe a kind of orange rectangle appears between the keyframes but i can't see the actual yellow dot that are normally on the software.
Please, if someone knows what to do please tell me, i would be really thankful.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the header of the Dope Sheet you have selected to show only animation channels that have errors:

[image]

De-select this to show your keyframes.